# Need help importing account from wallets such as MetaMask, Coinbase, etc into Brownie

Tags: metamask, brownie

Apologize in advance if this question was already asked before.

I was looking for a way to programmatically pull the account from MetaMask (or some other wallet) and add it to brownie. The problem I keep facing is that I can't add the account in Brownie without knowing the private key/ keystore file. As far as I can tell, there really isn't a direct way to programmatically get the private key from MetaMask.

How am I supposed to import a real account into brownie? Maybe there is a way other than using a private key or a keystore file?

*Yes, I know I can export the private key from MetaMask, but that can't be done programmatically.

I also looked into some eth_requestAccounts method that Metamask has in its documentation, but that still didn't seem to answer my question.